# Null pointer exception on indeterminate progressbar on actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

So I have started creating an app which uses jsoup to scrap stocks data. When I move from home activity to the 'Stocks' activity through the navigation drawer, I require the resulting activity to show the first fragment (recyclerview in a viewpager) which scrapes and lists all stocks. However, this always results in the following error. However, if the fragment is put as the third fragment and opened as shown in the picture below (Edit: can't post pictures yet), it works as expected.

> 9200-9200/com.blueinklabs.investmentportfoliopakistan
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.blueinklabs.investmentportfoliopakistan, PID: 9200
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)' on a
>   null object reference at
>   com.blueinklabs.investmentportfoliopakistan.StocksActivity.showProgressBar(StocksActivity.java:68)
>   at
>   com.blueinklabs.investmentportfoliopakistan.StockData$Title.onPreExecute(StockData.java:37)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539) at
>   com.blueinklabs.investmentportfoliopakistan.StockData.(StockData.java:28)
>   at
>   com.blueinklabs.investmentportfoliopakistan.StocksCompleteListFragment.getSymbols(StocksCompleteListFragment.java:63)
>   at
>   com.blueinklabs.investmentportfoliopakistan.StocksCompleteListFragment.setupRecyclerView(StocksCompleteListFragment.java:55)
>   at
>   com.blueinklabs.investmentportfoliopakistan.StocksCompleteListFragment.onCreateView(StocksCompleteListFragment.java:48)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141) at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105) at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951) at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:573)
>   at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:640)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) at
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613) at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:588

I think the issue is that the async task (below) happens before the onPrepareOptionsMenu loads. Error Happens at the PreExecute in the class below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class StockData {
    private ArrayList<String> symbolList;
    Context myContext;
    RecyclerView recyclerV;

    public StockData(Context getcontext, RecyclerView recyclerView){
        myContext = getcontext;
        symbolList = new ArrayList<String>();
        recyclerV = recyclerView;
        new Title().execute();
    }

    private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String title;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ((StocksActivity) myContext).showProgressBar();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("websiteurl").get();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Element table = doc.select("table.mGrid").get(1);
            Elements rows = table.select("tr");
            Iterator<Element> rowIterator = rows.iterator();
            rowIterator.next();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Element row = rowIterator.next();
                Elements cols = row.select("td");
                symbolList.add(cols.get(1).text());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            ((StocksCompleteListFragment.SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter) recyclerV.getAdapter()).changeList(symbolList);
            ((StocksActivity) myContext).hideProgressBar();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSymbolList(){
        return symbolList;
    }


}
```

The StocksActivity.java is as follows:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * TODO
 */
public class StocksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public MenuItem miActionProgressItem;

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Store instance of the menu item containing progress
        miActionProgressItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mi_ActionProgress);
        // Extract the action-view from the menu item
        ProgressBar v = (ProgressBar) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(miActionProgressItem);
        // Return to finish
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void showProgressBar() {
        // Show progress item
        miActionProgressItem.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void hideProgressBar() {
        // Hide progress item
        miActionProgressItem.setVisible(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stocks);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
            final Menu navMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
            ((MenuItem) navMenu.findItem(R.id.menuItem1)).setChecked(true);
            final ArrayList<View> mMenuItems = new ArrayList<>(navigationView.getChildCount());
            //for (int i = 0; i < navigationView.getChildCount(); i++){
            navigationView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    // Remember to remove the installed OnGlobalLayoutListener
                    navigationView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    // Loop through and find each MenuItem View
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        final String id = "menuItem" + (i);
                        final MenuItem item = navMenu.findItem(getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName()));
                        navigationView.findViewsWithText(mMenuItems, item.getTitle(), View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT);
                    }
                    // Loop through each MenuItem View and apply your custom Typeface
                    for (final View menuItem : mMenuItems) {
                        ((TextView) menuItem).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        ((TextView) menuItem).setTextSize(14);
                    }
                }
            });
            //}

        }

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        if (viewPager != null) {
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Here's a Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample_actions, menu);
        miActionProgressItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mi_ActionProgress);
        // Extract the action-view from the menu item
        ProgressBar v = (ProgressBar) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(miActionProgressItem);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new StocksCompleteListFragment(), "Category 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "All Stocks");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menuItem0:
                                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(mainIntent);
                                finish();
                                break;
                            case R.id.menuItem1:
                                Intent stocksIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StocksActivity.class);
                                startActivity(stocksIntent);
                                finish();
                                break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }

    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

I have spent the last 8 hours trying to solve this issue and this is my first time posting on this forum so please excuse if I have incorrectly posted this. I have already searched and tried a few solution I think were relevant.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxxr6.png

EDIT: heres the class of the fragment StocksCompleteListFragment.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StocksCompleteListFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<String> list;
    RecyclerView rv;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rv = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_stocks_completelist, container, false);
        setupRecyclerView(rv);
        return rv;
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                getSymbols(recyclerView)));

    }


    private ArrayList<String> getSymbols(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        StockData stockDataClass = new StockData(getActivity(), recyclerView);
        list = stockDataClass.getSymbolList();
        return list;
    }

    public static class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
        private int mBackground;
        private List<String> mValues;

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public String mBoundString;

            public final View mView;
            public final ImageView mImageView;
            public final TextView mTextView;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
                mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return super.toString() + " '" + mTextView.getText();
            }
        }

        public void changeList (ArrayList<String> tempStringList) {
            mValues = tempStringList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public String getValueAt(int position) {
            return mValues.get(position);
        }

        public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
            context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, mTypedValue, true);
            mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;
            mValues = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.completestocks_listitem, parent, false);
            view.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mBoundString = mValues.get(position);
            holder.mTextView.setText(mValues.get(position));

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CheeseDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(CheeseDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, holder.mBoundString);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
                    .load(Cheeses.getRandomCheeseDrawable())
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(holder.mImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mValues.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing your `showProgressBar` and `hideProgressBar` to your `AsyncTask` and passing a reference to the menu as a parameter. You're getting that error because when you call those methods no reference exists to the `MenuItem`.

Comment: The log said that your context "myContext" is null. Can you show the code that used StockData?

Comment: Eric, based on your suggestion, I used the getActivity() method in my fragment class to access the MenuItem from StocksActivity.java. Then passed it to Async class (StockData) and also shifted the methods to this class. Still shows the null pointer. Seriously stuck!

Comment: John, I've inserted the fragment class in the post edit. Would be glad if you could help!

Comment: From what I can understand, the menu item is being called before it is instantiated in StocksActivity in the onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method. But I need to launch the asynctask immediately as well so I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Or wait, should I properly pass the parameters to the fragment class through bundles? Isn't getContext and casting it to StocksActivity a valid way of getting data from the StocksActivity?

Comment: Tried so many other things. This just won't go away. Can you guys please help? I can't even take help from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of difficult to explain what it could be in a comment, so I'll help you debugging in this answer.

So, `StockActivity` loads the fragments and `StocksCompleteListFragment` executes the `AsyncTask` (this last one access the `StockActivity`'s menu item). 
`AsyncTask` (`StockData`'s inner class) should receive a reference to the `MenuItem`.

I would try, like I told you earlier, move both methods accessing the `MenuItem` to the `AsyncTask`.

```java
private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showProgressBar();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ((StocksCompleteListFragment.SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter) recyclerV.getAdapter()).changeList(symbolList);
        hideProgressBar();
    }


    // I don't need them to be public if I move them here
    //
    private void showProgressBar() {
    // Show progress item
        item.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void hideProgressBar() {
        // Hide progress item
        item.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

After that, you should pass the `MenuItem` to the `StocksCompleteListFragment` so :

Add a constructor which receives it

```java
public class StocksCompleteListFragment extends Fragment {
    private MenuItem item;

    // Default constructor
    public StocksCompleteListFragment() {}

    public StocksCompleteListFragment(MenuItem item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    // ...
```

Then pass it to the Fragment class

```java
// StocksActivity.java

adapter.addFragment(new StocksCompleteListFragment(miActionProgressItem ), "Category 1");
```

Later pass the item from `StocksCompleteListFragment` to the `StockData` class so the inner `AsyncTask`can have access to it

```java
public class StockData {
    private ArrayList<String> symbolList;
    Context myContext;
    RecyclerView recyclerV;
    private MenuItem item;

    public StockData(Context getcontext, RecyclerView recyclerView){
        myContext = getcontext;
        symbolList = new ArrayList<String>();
        recyclerV = recyclerView;
        new Title().execute();
    }

    public StockData(Context getcontext, RecyclerView recyclerView, MenuItem item) {
        this(getcontext, recyclerView);
        this.item = item;
    }
```

And finally edit your pieace of code calling the `AsyncTask` to pass the `MenuItem`

```java
private ArrayList<String> getSymbols(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    StockData stockDataClass = new StockData(getActivity(), recyclerView, item);
    list = stockDataClass.getSymbolList();
    return list;
}
```

If I'm in the right track, the `MenuItem` should exist already when you call the `AsyncTask`.
I'm seeing it like this :

**StockActivity** (fully loaded, action bar and everything) -> pass the menu item -> **StocksCompleteListFragment** (call the `AsyncTask`) -> pass menu item -> **AsyncTask** hides/shows the menu item.

This is how I see it, there must be an easier option, but I can't come up with anything easier.

Try this, I would rather this to be a comment more than an answer, but I can't write this much.

Just keep trying, I'll comeback tomorrow to track this thread. I hope it helps you a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for your help man, but this still does not work :( I put two logs right before the fragments are created to know if the menu is null at that stage, and it is. So most probably a case of progressbar asking for menu reference before it is even setup. Explains why is works as the third fragment.

        if (miActionProgressItem == null){
            Log.w("myApp", "MenuItem is Null");
        }
        else {
            Log.w("myApp", "MenuItem is Filled");
        }

adapter.addFragment(new StocksCompleteListFragment(miActionProgressItem), "Category 1");

Comment: I have already worked on an alternative implementation of having the progressbar on top of the fragment itself, so that should work in case this doesnt resolve

Comment: Well, I couldn't find another way, I'm really sorry. If you found another way it should be nice if you share it and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Eric, thanks a lot. I didn't find any answer to my question despite trying alot. So I shifted from progressbar in actionbar to progressbar in my fragment.